# Why does ubuntu freeze sometimes when I shut my laptop screen

Tags: login, power-management, screen, lenovo, freeze

I own a Lenovo Y50 running Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit and sometimes when Ii shut the screen the login screen is displayed after I open it back up again, but it is unresponsive and I can't do anything from the touchpad or keyboard.

Comment: You are having difficulty with the "Power Management" subsystem.  Look at `dpkg -L pm-utils`, and `/var/log/pm*`. Search this site for "Power Management"

Comment: im not too familiar with the terminal, what do i have to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Before we can supply a solution, we need to determine what the problem is. Almost all of my approaches to linux problem solving involve using the terminal to diagnose.  Use "Applications Menu->Utilities->System Log", click the gear in the upper right corner, select "Open" to view `/var/log/pm*`. Have you typed "Power management" and/or "Lenovo Y50" into the search box for AskUbuntu?

Comment: how do i get to the applications menu option? and no i have not looked those up as im a busy person and really dont have the time to thoroughly investigate technology issues

Comment: Me neither. Good luck.

Comment: your response is sarcastic and disrespectful and i dont appreciate it. i would like to know which gear icon you were talking about bc i dont see one

Comment: You seem to want us to solve your problem with no effort on your part. Since we are all contributing to AskUbuntu voluntarily, without compen$ation, and are all "busy persons", we don't have time to try to intuit what your problems are, or try to teach you how to use a computer. Yes, my response was sarcastic and disrespectful. I have no respect for people who ask a technical question, supplying insufficient detail, and respond to requests for more detail with "im a busy person and really dont have the time to thoroughly investigate technology issues".  I don't have time either.

Comment: i am willing to devote enough time to get this problem fixed

Comment: lets not argue and get this problem solved plsd

Comment: i apologize for anything i have said that may have sounded disrespectful

Comment: "i am willing to devote enough time to get this problem fixed", really? OK. When your computer is NOT frozen, and you are logged in, graphically, look at the very top of your  screen. at the left edge (on MY system, YMMV) for "Applications". Left click and hold. Explore in that menu structure as described above to find a system log reader. Have you followed any of my other suggestions? If not, please do.

Comment: im at the system settings menu but theres no options for applications on this screen. 

also how do i get to the applications menu

Comment: Try the other corners. `System settings` is of no use until we determine what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It's the noveau graphics driver, switch to the nvidia drivers and everything will be fine. I have a y50 myself and have been facing this issue for a while. To easily switch to the nvidia drivers, press the win key, type "drivers", enter, make sure you're on the additional drivers tab, then check nvidia binary driver and apply the changes. Then boom, resume/suspend works. You can now close your laptop without worrying about freezing.

Comment: "It's the noveau graphics driver" 100% correct. I had the same issues with 15.10. Dump that driver fixed all my crashes and not booting and screen locking up when closing the lid.